# FirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched() is deprecated. What to use instead?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

[Firebase Remote Config **activateFetched()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android) is deprecated. What to use instead?

```
firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
```

Comment: You can usually find this information in the release notes, by searching for the method name. For example, this is the version that contains the information about `activateFetched()`'s removal: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#version_1650

Answer (score 20):

Use `firebaseRemoteConfig.activate();` instead. See documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#activate()

Answer (score 9):

Use **activate()** instead.

```
firebaseRemoteConfig.activate();
```

I had to search for this. I hope it helps others.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use This.

RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate(completion: nil)

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.